# Alphabetical Comment Order?

Tags: comments

I’m using a modified comment form as a way to collect and display company names on this page:

http://www.drivesmartva.org/current-projects/distracted-driving/distracted-driving-safety-partners/

The orderby tag has worked well until now, but suddenly started listing new entries in chronological order at the bottom of the existing alphabetical list.

I've checked and double-checked the code, and everything seems in order:

```
<ul>
{exp:comment:entries orderby="comment" sort="asc" entry_id="{structure:page:entry_id}"}
<li>{comment}</li>
{/exp:comment:entries}
</ul>
```

Has anyone run into a similar problem with comment order?